# What is the easiest to create a module (which contain lots of html elements) instead of using appendChild?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a module that contains a huge group of html elements in Javascript and use `for` loop to create many of the module. The below is an example (I have more of html elements in the module, but in order to a create a minimal example, I reduce most of them.

```js
function create() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    //img.src = source[i].url
    let pho = document.createElement('div')
    pho.className = 'pho'
    let button = document.createElement('button')
    button.textContent = "♡"
    let border = document.createElement('div')
    let hr = document.createElement('hr')
    pho.appendChild(button)
    pho.appendChild(img)
    border.appendChild(hr)
    border.appendChild(pho)
    document.body.appendChild(border)
  }
}
create()
```

In the above example, I am trying to use `appendChild` to create a parent element (`border`) that contain several children elements.

It works find, but the code looks too massy and hard to deal if I have more of them.

Could anyone suggest me a better way of doing this?

Thanks for any responds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an HTML string instead?

```
const createBorder = (url) => {
  const div = document.body.appendChild(createElement('div'));
  div.innerHTML = `
    <hr>
    <div class="pho">
      <button>♡</button>
      <img>
    </div>
  `;
  // avoid XSS vulnurabilities by not interpolating the dynamic value
  // directly into the HTML string
  div.querySelector('img').src = url;
};
function create() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    createBorder(source[i].url);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just wonder will this method also works for `addEventListener`. For example, I want the `img` to be hidden if user click on `button`. If I use the `DOM.createElement`, I have already define the name for each element when I created it so I could dicectly make the `eventListener`, but by use the template literal, I doesn't define the name for each element.

Comment: Yep, with this approach, creating the markup is a lot easier, but to do stuff with individual elements, you'll have to select them first, Just like with setting the src, you'd need something like `div.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => ...` For non-tiny applications, if you find yourself having to do this a lot, I'd strongly consider something like React instead - the logic gets a lot cleaner

Comment: I will try to see if React.js works later. Thanks for the advise. Another question, will `CustomElementRegistry.define()` be a good way to solve the problem? I checked its documentation and it seems like a way to custom a html tag. Since I never used it before, I don't know if it will be a great way  and could solve my situation or not?

Comment: Others may have different opinions, but personally, I would not. They have a separate API and so will take some learning to get used to, and don't offer much that vanilla DOM manipulation can't do with nearly the same amount of code.